# Ubuntu 16.10 install

Tags: workspaces, cursor

Help would be appreciated with the following three problems, following upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 from 16.04, having chosen the option of total erasure of hard disc followed by 16.10 and installing all Ubuntu-recommended upgrades:

1. sticky cursor, especially at sides of screen,
   and occasional disappearance of cursor
2. severe flickering of program identification tags
   when cursor is over program icon in dash
3. workspaces:  only alternate workspaces function horizontally:
   from left, 1st no, 2nd yes;  3rd no, 4th yes

My computer specs are:

```
64-bit;   intel pentium G4400@3.3GHz x2;
intel 510 skylake GTI;
7.5Gb RAM;    975Gb hard disc
```

I am a relative newbie and grateful for any guidance!

Garfie